# Code size concerns with variadic templates

Tags: c++, templates, design-patterns, variadic-templates, variadic-functions

I am creating an algorithm that deals with many different user defined types at once. Each of these types will be assumed to have a `func1` and `func2` that will be the interface for `MyAlgorithm`. I can do this using variadic templates:

```
template <typename... Args>
class MyAlgorithm{
    // interact with Args using func1 and func2
};
```

I can now instantiate `MyAlgorithm` like so `MyAlgorithm<A, B, C, D, E, F, G>`. This works, however, I feel as though for my application this may result in too many specializations of `MyAlgorithm`. In practice, `MyAlgorithm` may be instantiated first like `MyAlgorithm<A, B, B , A, C, D>`, then `MyAlgorithm<A, A, C, D>`, and then `MyAlgorithm<C, F D>`, and so on.

Unfortunately, the template is instantiated for every combination of `Args`. This creates problems, for example, in the online setting. `MyAlgorithm` may be run on batches of live input data (the nature of `MyAlgorithm` is that it runs on batches rather than individual inputs). The live input data will be parsed and the correct specialization of `MyAlgorithm` will be called. In this case, the user will need to create all possible specializations of `MyAlgorithm` in the compiled code.

```
MyAlgorithm<A>;
MyAlgorithm<B>;
MyAlgorithm<C>;
MyAlgorithm<A, A>;
MyAlgorithm<A, B>;
MyAlgorithm<A, C>;
MyAlgorithm<B, A>;
...
```

I had an idea that may be able to help, but I haven't gotten it exactly right. Instead of `MyAlgorithm` taking template parameters, it will deal with a template `Proxy` class that is specialized to the `A, B, Cs`.

```
// no template 
class MyAlgorithm{
    // interact with Proxy using func1proxy and func2proxy
    std::vector<Proxy> Args;
};

template<typename T>
class Proxy{
    // define func1proxy and func2proxy using Arg's func1 and func2
    std::unique_ptr<T> Arg; // only member
};
```

Of course this doesn't work because each `Proxy` specialization is a different class and so `MyAlgorithm` still needs to be a template class (and `std::vector<Proxy> Args` can't exist).

Is there a design pattern for what I want to do? Is there a design pattern that reduces the number of class instantiations?

**Some notes:**

`MyAlgorithm` treats all template arguments the same. The algorithm recursively calls `func1` and `func2` on each template argument.

```
class MyAlgorithm{
    template<typname T, typename... Args>
    void CallFunc1s(T first, Args... rest){
        T.func1();
        SomeFunction(rest);
    }
};
```

Comment: There is no turnkey solution for this very common issue. Each situation is unique. You need to analyze which part of your template can be cleanly factored out into a non-template class in order to minimize the code bloat. No amount of "design pattern" Buzzword Bingo is a substitute for a thorough analysis of the code's logic, and proper refactoring. Perhaps if you restate your question clearly, a more practical suggestion can be offered: you started your question by mentioning something called `func` and `func2`, that never gets mentioned again. What is that supposed to mean?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik The point is that ```MyAlgorithm``` only interacts with the template arguments through calling ```func1``` and ```func2```. It does not interact with data members of the template parameters, except through ```func1``` and ```func2```. It <may> not need to know the type of the template parameters, but only how to call the type's ```func1``` and ```func2```. I imagined that there might be a solution that uses function pointers, which I don't use much. 

In particular, it will not call a ```func3``` if one of the ```Args``` has a ```func3``` and not otherwise.

Comment: I don't know what "interacting with template arguments" means. Template arguments are types. Function parameters are objects and values, and types. In any case, as I outlined, the way to reduce the code bloat is to factor out as much code and data into non-template code.

Comment: Can you make your example a bit more concrete?

Comment: You should show us a [mcve] where code bloat is present. It's difficult to help you in the abstract.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica I added this: "This creates problems, for example, in the online setting. ```MyAlgorithm``` may be run on batches of live input data (the nature of ```MyAlgorithm``` is that it runs on batches rather than individual inputs). The live input data will be parsed and the correct specialization of ```MyAlgorithm``` will be called. In this case, the user will need to create all possible specializations of ```MyAlgorithm``` in the compiled code." I hope that is more concrete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type erase a type T to be called by func1/func2.

```
struct proxy_ref{
  void* pdata=0;
  void(*pfunc1)(void*)=0;
  void(*pfunc2)(void*)=0;
  template<class T>
  proxy_ref(T&& t):
    pdata((void*)std::addressof(t)),
    pfunc1([](void*pvoid){
      ((T*)pvoid)->func1();
    }),
    pfunc2([](void*pvoid){
      ((T*)pvoid)->func2();
    })
  {}
  void func1(){ pfunc1(pvoid); }
  void func2(){ pfunc2(pvoid); }
};
```

now take a vector of `proxy_ref`s and call `func1` and `func2` on them.

Your particular problem could involve more complex signatures, or even value types instead of ref types.

There are problems like yours that type erasure cannot solve, but trying this is a first step.

Comment: This is exactly the kind of thing I was looking for. I'm guessing there is no memory safe way to do this?

Comment: @mana I do not know what you mean by memory safe.  You mean value semantics?  Yes you can do value semantics; just erase copy/move/destroy ctors and dtor like I did func1.

Comment: I guess I have been taught that the best way to be memory safe is to "never use raw pointers." Let me use an example. The user of my code creates 2 objects ```A a; B b;```. They pass these to ```MyAlgorithm```, ```MyAlgorithm(a, b);```. I believe that something like this should be equivalent to ```MyAlgorithm(proxy_ref<A>(a), proxy_ref<B>(b))```. Now, I want to prevent ```a``` and ```b``` from being deleted before ```proxy_ref``` is done with them, but I also want them to be deleted if proxy_ref holds the last pointer to them. Usually I would use ```shared_ptr```, but that is a template class.

Comment: @mana proxy ref isn't a template.  Second, the sensible choices are not raw pointer or shared ptr, they are value semantics (regular or semi regular), shared ownership semantics, or reference semantics.  Here I demonstrated reference semantics (non-owning).  The other two are quite doable, but using shared ownership with syntax like you demonstrated would be toxic...

Comment: Value or non owning reference are usually best.  If your algorithm runs and does not store the proxies, non owning reference semantics is safe and cheap.  If not, I'd implement value semantics.  Shared ownership of mutable objects is insanely hard to get right, it is a trap.